# loop statement breaking

Tags: php

please why is the loop statement breaking, after the multiplication it only update the last row, tried using a foreach loop for the $totalprice in the update statement it says invalid argument.

```
if(array_key_exists('item', $_POST)){


// $items = $_POST['item'];
  //foreach($_POST['item'] as $item){
    //echo $item['Pquantity'] . ", ";
    //echo $item['Pidno'] . ", ";
   // }
    //Loop through $_POST items, updating the database for each item
    foreach ($_POST['item'] as $item) { 
        $Pquantity = intval($item['Pquantity']);
        $Pidno = ($item['Pidno']); 
        //echo $Pquantity . ", ";
        //echo $Pidno . ", ";
        //$totalprice = intval($item['Pquantity']) 
        $queryreg = mysql_query("
            UPDATE repplac
                 SET Pquantity = {$Pquantity}
                 WHERE
                       Pidno = '{$Pidno}'
                 AND
                       Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
        ") or die(mysql_error());  

    }
    }
    $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) 
  {
  $totalprice = $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];
  //echo "$totalprice";
  //die();
   $queryreg = mysql_query("
  UPDATE repplac
  SET Tprice = {$totalprice}
  WHERE
                       Pidno = '{$Pidno}'
                 AND
                       Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
    ") or die(mysql_error());  
  }
```

Comment: Please better describe what is and is not happening. This question is close to incomprehensible.

Comment: after the multiplication of the value  $totalprice = $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];    the values in the array, are to update the database, but it only update one row, so its like after the multiplication, it breaks out and update one row

Comment: Is $Pidno set and is Pidno a column of that table?

Comment: The WHERE clause is not changed, so is there only one row that matches the WHERE clause for the UPDATE command?

Comment: @djot was defined $Pidno in a prior statement  and Pidno a column in the table i have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `foreach` you update `$Pidno` with the following code

```
$Pidno = ($item['Pidno']);
```

Thus you are updating different records in the database. But inside your `while` loop `$Pidno` is staying the same the entire time. Thus you are updating the same record over and over. To fix this add the following code at the beginning of the `while` loop

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)) 
{
    //get the correct Pidno for this row
    $Pidno = ($row['Pidno']); 
    $totalprice = $row['Price'] * $row['Pquantity'];

    // ... the rest of your while loop
```

Comment: thanks, i never knew i had to assign the  $Pidno = ($row['Pidno']);, was thinking it should serve as a pointer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Neither arguments in the second condition gets changed inside the loop:

```
WHERE
                   Pidno = '{$Pidno}'
             AND
                   Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}
```

Perhaps you forgot to update `$Pidno`?

Also, I don't think the following is safe:

```
"SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'"
```

You might want to sanitize `$_SESSION['username']` before passing it to the query.

Comment: for the Pidno = '{$Pidno}', it was defined it a previous code

Comment: @lostty84 I agree, but the update will operate on the same row, since the condition is the same for all iterations.

Comment: `if(array_key_exists('item', $_POST)){
   
  
    foreach ($_POST['item'] as $item) { 
        $Pquantity = intval($item['Pquantity']);
        $Pidno = ($item['Pidno']); 
        //echo $Pquantity . ", ";
     //echo $Pidno . ", ";
     //$totalprice = intval($item['Pquantity']) 
        $queryreg = mysql_query("
            UPDATE repplac
                 SET Pquantity = {$Pquantity}
                 WHERE
                       Pidno = '{$Pidno}'
                 AND
                       Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
        ") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: that means i have to define it again in the loop

Comment: @lostty84 would you mind updating your question with the code you put in that comment? It'll make it much easier to read in context and with proper formatting.

Comment: @jb,would it be a new thread, cos i dont know ow to format on the "add comment"

Comment: @lostty84 look at the top of this page, right underneath your question before the answers begin. You should see the links `link|edit|flag`. Click on `edit` and you can add in this new code to your original code.

Comment: if i remove the pidno statement and only validate with username it updates everything just with one value

Comment: @lostty84 What I said is the cause for your problem. Now, we don't know the logic of your program. **You** should.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore i agree with you  "Perhaps you forgot to update $Pidno?"